# Text widget is placing everything side by side. I want to post it above

Tags: theme-development, themes, widgets, text, widget-text

As I add text widgets within a page in my home screen, They are going side by side. I have three text widgets as if there are three columns of text in my page. I like this, but i want to put a title above... so I want to add another text widget. Once I add this text widget, it appears as another column on the right. Where would i go to fix something like this? do i make the change in my theme/css/or is this something I can do in the UI of wordpress admin?

I'm new to wordpress so i'm still learning the whereabouts. Thanks!

Comment: Can you link to the page you are seeing this happen or provide a screenshot?

Comment: you can quite likely change it in the CSS of your theme. a good place to ask for help with that would be the developer of your theme or a support forum of your theme if there is one.